# Какое правильное определение у SCOPE (Скоуп)

Tags: php, scope

Часто сталкиваюсь с таким понятием как `scope` но не понимаю его. Скажите точное определение что такое `scope` и прошу приложить 2-3 примера по возможности на `php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Область видимости переменной - это контекст, в котором эта переменная определена. В большинстве случаев все переменные PHP имеют только одну область видимости. Эта единая область видимости охватывает также включаемые **(include)** и требуемые **(require)** файлы. Например:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
include 'b.inc';
?>
```

Здесь переменная `$a` будет доступна внутри включенного скрипта `b.inc`. Однако определение (тело) пользовательской функции задает локальную область видимости данной функции. Любая используемая внутри функции переменная по умолчанию ограничена локальной областью видимости функции. Например:

```
<?php
$a = 1; /* глобальная область видимости */ 

function test()
{ 
    echo $a; /* ссылка на переменную локальной области видимости */ 
} 

test();
?>
```

Этот скрипт не сгенерирует никакого вывода, поскольку выражение `echo` указывает на локальную версию переменной `$a`, а в пределах этой области видимости ей не было присвоено значение. Возможно вы заметили, что это немного отличается от языка C в том, что глобальные переменные в C автоматически доступны функциям, если только они не были перезаписаны локальным определением. Это может вызвать некоторые проблемы, поскольку люди могут нечаянно изменить глобальную переменную. В PHP, если глобальная переменная будет использоваться внутри функции, она должна быть объявлена глобальной внутри определения функции.

[Источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php)